# sync tabular model from single server to the two different servers at same time

Tags: synchronization, ssas, cube, ssas-tabular

I have one SSAS tabular model on one server and want to sync the same to more than one server at same time will it impact any thing on the speed or performance.

currently the tabular model is getting synced one at a time but the same model I want to sync to two servers at same time.

Comment: You should look at the server stats first. Are you hitting high CPU or memory? It's a whole lot easier to add memory to a server than to do as you are thinking.